# Create Dynamic Connection in asp.net c# on run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  want to create of dynamic connection string of dynamic  database.I have login page in asp.net c#.Where user can enter the database name and database user/password.I want user can login according to db name and db user and password.I do not want to  create dynamic connection in web.config file because when i dynamically change the web.config file application again will be restart.Is there any way to do this.I have multiple per user of different database and different user name and different password.How can i acheive this on run time.Different database uses same application.I want every user can connect according to his database.

```
string Constring = generateConnectiontring();
    public string generateConnectiontring()
            {
                var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                var stringChars = new char[8];
                var random = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
                {
                    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                }

                var finalString = new String(stringChars);
                return finalString;
            }
```

and now I want to create a dynamic connection with dynamic database name and password.Same to like php.I want to define database and credentials in page.

Comment: A connection string is just that...a connection string.  Pull back combinations stored in a database table, check permissions, and construct your string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
    {
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
       command.Connection.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: no i do not know the database name and user name.I think you are not  getting me

Comment: i further modified my connection